# How to specify default Enum instance for Guice?

Tags: java, enums, default, guice

I'd need something like

```
@DefaultInstance(Level.NORMAL)
enum Level {NORMAL, FANCY, DEBUGGING}
```

which would make Guice to return `Level.NORMAL` for the expression

```
injector.getInstance(Level.class)
```

There's no such thing like `@DefaultInstance`. As a workaround I've tried `@ProvidedBy` with a trivial `Provider`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried: `bind(Level.class).toInstance(Level.NORMAL)` or do you require an annotation based solution?

Comment: The explicit binding works fine, but I want to provide a default (using annotations). I use the enum quite often and nearly always need NORMAL. I'm writing a lot of small programs and always doing an explicit configuration is really boring.

Comment: What was the error with the `@ProvidedBy` attempt?

Comment: Exactly the same as if there were no binding at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [the issue 295](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=295&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Extension) and looks like a very trivial bug.

I've patched it for myself and maybe one day somebody there will fix this very old issue, too.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe overriding modules could help you. A default level can be configured using `AppLevel` module:

```
public class AppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(Level.class).toInstance(Level.NORMAL);
        // other bindings
    }
}
```

and a specific one can be configured in a small overriding module:

```
public class FancyLevelModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(Level.class).toInstance(Level.FANCY);
    }
}
```

At the end just create an injector overriding the `AppModule` with a specific `Level` config:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = 
        Guice.createInjector(
            Modules.override(new AppModule()).with(new FancyLevelModule())
    );

    System.out.println("level = " + injector.getInstance(Level.class));
}
```

**UPDATE**

This problem can be solved in a bit different way. Let's say that `Level` is used in a class as an injected field:

```
class Some
{
  @Injected(optional = true)
  private Level level = Level.NORMAL;
}
```

A default level will be initialized as part of the creation of instances of `Some`. If some Guice config module declares some other level it will be optionally injected.

Comment: The overriding itself works fine.
My problem lies on the side where I'm satisfied with the default and don't even want to know that a `Level` gets used.
The enum class itself knows what a suitable default is.
When each user of the class must provide a default, it's no default anymore.

Comment: How does the enum class know what's a suitable default value? I thought it is just a collection of singleton, immutable objects with implicit ordering.

Comment: Would "the designer of the enum knowns" sound better?

Comment: How does a `Charset` know its `defaultCharset()`? It's just a bunch of named mappings.... or `Locale.getDefault()`? Those classes are much more complicated, but in the end their designer guessed what the user would like to use when he/she doesn't care much, that's all.

Answer (score 5):

A solution, but unfortunatelly not using annotations, would be:

```
enum Level 
{
    NORMAL, FANCY, DEBUGGING;

    static final Level defaultLevel = FANCY; //put your default here
}
```

then define module like this:

```
public class DefaultLevelModule extends AbstractModule 
{
    @Override public void configure() 
    {
        bind(Level.class).toInstance(Level.defaultLevel);
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is not annotations vs. something else, but implicit vs. explicit. As I wrote elsewhere, the enum gets used a lot and nearly always I need the same instance. Doing *anything* explicitly is useless boilerplate. See also my [comments here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5179430/581205).

Comment: So you actually don't need the second part and can use the default static field directly :)

Comment: IOW I don't need no injection at all. :D Unless I do.